# Flutter - Error Could not Find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter

im new on flutter, and i experience some troubles after i add a new provider into my main.

this is my main code:

```
import 'package:catalo_gate/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:catalo_gate/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:catalo_gate/services/products_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'screens/screens.dart';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(const AppState());
}

class AppState extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppState({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ProductsService()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => LoginProvider(authService: AuthService())),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CataloGate',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: 'login',
      routes: {
        'login': (BuildContext context) => const LoginScreen(),
        'register': (BuildContext context) => const RegisterScreen(),
        'checking': (BuildContext context) => const CheckAuthScreen(),
        'home': (BuildContext context) => const HomeScreen(),
        'product': (BuildContext context) => const ProductScreen(),
        'productsList': (BuildContext context) => const ProductsListScreen(),
        //SubScreens
        'listaReposicion': (BuildContext context) =>
            const ListaDiasReposicionScreen(),
        'entregas': (BuildContext context) => const DiasDeEntregaScreen(),
        'unidadesPorBulto': (BuildContext context) =>
            const UnidadesPorBultoScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

everytime i try to make login i receive this message:

ProviderNotFoundException (Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this HomeScreen Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that HomeScreen is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
)

Can someone Help me??

i'd try a lot of options, changing the way to use the ChangeNotifierProvider for example

Comment: The problem seems to be answered by the last block of code that you quoted, just above where it says *If none of these solutions work*. Did you read the contents of that section?

Comment: @Fer Haring, can you please add code where you are trying to use the provider object.